# clean history script not working

Tags: command-line, scripts, history

I'm creating a script to run in the start up that says:

```
_cleanthehistory ()
{
/bin/echo "cleaning the history"
history -c
}
_cleanthehistory
```

The deal here is that this does not work from the script, but if I run it from the command line works.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
Pablo.

Comment: Is this the whole script or did you put that somewhere (e.g. in the `bashrc`)? If so, please post the whole script. If not, why did you write it inside a function instead of a plain `/bin/echo "cleaning the history"; history -c`. Also I think you're missing a semicolon in the version posted here.

Comment: Hi, yes this is a section of the script.

Comment: As I said, there is a semicolon missing between the `echo` and the `history` command. Also if you do that from within a script you do it from the local scope of the script. Very much the same if you change a variable within a script it is not changed outside (in the terminal you ran the script in).

Comment: @con-f-use there are actually newlines there, they were just turned into spaces due to using the wrong formatting (for this site).

Comment: @geirha is right is because of the format of this site.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment `history -c` just deletes the history of the current session, i.e. only the commands your script ran. To clear all data including old sessions you'll have to do something like

```
rm -f $HOME/.bash_history
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'll try deleting the .bash_history file.

Comment: It didn't worked. :(

Comment: cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history

:)
Thanks to all for the help!.

Answer (score 0):

History is only enabled for interactive shells, not scripts. So in a script, `history -c` won't do much good. If you just want to empty your user's bash history during boot, as `/tmp` is emptied during boot, just truncate or delete `~/.bash_history`.

```
echo "cleaning the history"
> /home/yourusername/.bash_history
```

This uses shell redirection without a command. It makes the shell just open the file for writing (truncating it if it already exists), then close it without writing anything to it (since there's no command to write anything to it).

On a side note, don't use absolute paths to commands in scripts. E.g. use `echo`, not `/bin/echo`.

**update**: Or if you don't want to save bash history at all, you could put something like `HISTFILE=/dev/null` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks @geirha I've tried that but didn't worked also, is really weird, in a debian server works like a charm, but not in the ubuntu .

Comment: @pma083 How exactly are you running it at start up?